# Could not find a working python interpreter. Unity, Firebase

Tags: python, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Could not find a working python interpreter. Please make sure one of the following is in your PATH: python python3 python3.8 python3.7 python2.7 python2

I installed python 3.10.4
Path is set in environment variables. Still not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to set path:

1. Find the path to install Python on your computer. To do this, open the Windows search bar and type python.exe. Select the Open file location option.
2. Copy path of python folder.
3. To add Python To PATH In User Variables: Open My Computer\Properties\Advanced system settings\Advanced Environment Variables\Environment Variables.
4. In the User Variables menu, find a variable named Path. Then paste the path you copied earlier into the Variable Value option using Ctrl+v and click OK.
5. if you cannot find this variable, you may need to create it. To do this, click New. Then, in the variable name form, enter the path and paste your Python path into the variable value field.
   6.You can also add Python to the PATH system variable. Although this is just an alternative and not needed if you have already added it to the Users variables.

To use the System Variables option, follow the steps highlighted above to copy the Python path and its script. Then go back to environment variables. Then, in the system variables segment, look for a variable named Path. Click this variable and click Edit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It only started working for me after restarting Windows. I was going to suggest an edit, but got the error "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later."

Answer (score 3):

It is working now. We have to set paths in both user variables and system variables. Then restart the PC.

Comment: Hi Prathvi, I have the same error. Where did you set the path for user & system variables? And which paths did you alter?

Comment: Strangely, doing this did not fix the error for me :/

Comment: Don't you need to reset your computer to get the new path to take effect?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set the path and can see only python and/or python 3 in the destination folder:
Type "python" in cmd. It will automatically take you to Windows Store, Install python 3.8 from there. Or you can externally install python 3.8 for latest Firebase plugin. This removes the error.